# Passing translated text as function parametre, Angular

Tags: angular, parameters, translate

I am trying to pass translated string to function from HTML template in Angular, is it possible or maybe there might be some work around.

So far I have following code, which doesn't work

```
                        <div class="dataInner" (click)="displaySelected({{QCONSULTING.Strategy_consulting_details | translate}})">
                            <h1>Some title example text</h1>
                            <p>
                                {{"Turn your supply chain into a competitive weapon, one that's digital, sustainable and
                                more resilient than ever before." | truncate:[115, '...']}}
                            </p>
                            <span>
                                More ➤
                            </span>
                        </div>
```

This area is not working:

```
(click)="displaySelected({{QCONSULTING.Strategy_consulting_details | translate}})"
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for the curly braces. Just remove those and it should work:

`(click)="displaySelected(QCONSULTING.Strategy_consulting_details | translate)"`